# is there a e.ClickedItem for holding event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

Hi in my clicked event I am able to get the details of the button clicked with this

```
 private async void BedGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
     CommonVariables.PatientDetailsDict["bed_number"] = (e.ClickedItem as BedModelV2).bed_number;
                                    }
```

I was wondering if there is something similar for my holding event so I could get the information of the selected item. As the code below does not work with HoldingState or originalsource.

```
 private async void BedGridView_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     CommonVariables.PatientDetailsDict["bed_number"] = (e.OriginalSource as BedModelV2).bed_number;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using WP8.1 because `GridView` is supported in WP8.

To answer you question you can always get the SelectedItem of your GridView my referencing it by name or converting the `sender` object in the holding event like so:

```
<!-- define the gridview -->
<GridView x:Name="myGV" Holding="myGV_Holding"></GridView>
```

```C#
private void myGV_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var selectedItem = this.myGV.SelectedItem;                 // reference by name
     // var selectedItem = (sender as GridView).SelectedItem;   // reference by converting the sender

}
```

Once you got the .SelectedItem it will be an object based off your ViewModel so then you can convert it back like you did in your original code.

```
CommonVariables.PatientDetailsDict["bed_number"] = (selectedItem as BedModelV2).bed_number;
```

Comment: this only gives me the information for the first item regardless of which item I select

Comment: @user3929914 oh I see, you want the item it's currently holding, not the actual .SelectedItem?